# Where is centroid.h in PCL for ROS?

Tags: include, point-cloud-library, ros

I am trying to use the computeMeanAndCovarianceMatrix function from PCL in ROS. I researched online and saw that the function is defined in a centroid.hpp file, so I put `#include <pcl_ros/centroid.h>` at the top of my file but I still get a `No such file or directory #include <pcl_ros/centroid.h>`. Can someone help me with what include statement I have to put up so the function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to add `#include <pcl/common/centroid.h>`